# v2 app model, Office365 for native apps: AADSTS65005: Dynamic scope is invalid

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal

I have a problem with the Azure AD v2 authentication endpoint (v2 app model). Our application uses this endpoint and uses the Outlook REST API's.
I have two testaccounts:

1. a dev outlook.com account
2. an office365 account

I have build 2 ways of logging in:

1. Web Implicit flow
2. Native public client (no secret)

In total 4 scenario's:

- outlook.com with Web Implicit **WORKS**
- outlook.com with Native public client **WORKS**
- Office 365 with Web Implicit **WORKS**
- Office 365 with Native public client **FAILS**

The last scenario fails and we need it to work. It uses exactly the same code as the outlook.com scenario which works. First we
let the user login in a webcontrol, then the user accepts the permissions and then we get the id token.

We then use that to get the Access token and it fails for Office 365 with AADSTS65005: Dynamic scope is invalid: application...

See request details below.

Why? Can anyone reproduce or please help ?

Regards,

Jeroen

```
Request: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id=b75022be-f556-40ec-9785-c3639e65158b&
redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&
code=CODE_REMOVED_FOR_EXAMPLE&
session_state=98fb6ce4-e219-4265-8347-cc64199895a8&
grant_type=authorization_code
```

Response: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

```
{
  "error":"unauthorized_client",
  "error_description":"AADSTS65005: Dynamic scope is invalid: application 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 does not exist. Request ID: 94cd9ca3-c376-4d94-854e-bfc4f7ac3161, Timestamp: 02/26/2016 14:06:55\r\nTrace ID: 727ebe28-e7e2-4817-87fc-5f94b637c00e\r\nCorrelation ID: e4c5a448-3ba4-4de6-aaa9-df2f9c501ca5\r\nTimestamp: 2016-02-26 14:06:55Z",
  "error_codes":[65005],
  "timestamp":"2016-02-26 14:06:55Z",
  "trace_id":"727ebe28-e7e2-4817-87fc-5f94b637c00e",
  "correlation_id":"e4c5a448-3ba4-4de6-aaa9-df2f9c501ca5"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved the issue, it appeared that "scope=" parameter is also required in the request to https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token. It works now. 
A little bit strange that for outlook.com it also works without this parameter.

Comment: Is this new? I could have sworn it worked without the scope a month ago.